# Как привязать элемент списка к глобальной команде?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть окно с DataContext.
В окне список(ItemsControl).

Могу ли я указать для элемента списка команду, объявленную в DataContext окна?

Не пинайте, пожалуйста. Честно ковырял гугл, но так и не нашел решение.

Comment: Буквально перед вами по метке WPF был аналогичный вопрос, где я в комментарии описал что и как. Возьмите родителя через `FindAncestor` и привязывайтесь куда вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, @EvgeniyZ!

Вот пример кода с решением проблемы:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}" 
                Command="{Binding DataContext.BtnTagClickedCommand, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```